# Bootstrap datepicker - return inside a foreach function

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker and I am using beforeShowDay to select a few days to be enabled while disabling every date that is not the ones I selected.

```
    beforeShowDay : function(date) {
      var date1 = new Date([2017, 02, 23]);
      var date2 = new Date([2017, 04, 14]);
      var date3 = new Date([2017, 06, 12]);
      var dateArray = [date1, date2, date3];

      if (date.getTime() != date1.getTime() && date.getTime() != date2.getTime() && date.getTime() != date3.getTime()) {
        return {
          enabled: false
        };
      }
    }
```

I have this code that works, but I would like to convert into a foreach function as such :

```
    beforeShowDay : function(date) {
      var date1 = new Date([2017, 02, 23]);
      var date2 = new Date([2017, 04, 14]);
      var date3 = new Date([2017, 06, 12]);
      var dateArray = [date1, date2, date3];

      dateArray.forEach(doBleh());
      function doBleh(element) {
        if (datate.getTime() != element.getTime()) {
          return {
            enabled: false
          };
        }
      }
      return doBleh;
    }
```

This last piece of code does not work, I can't seem to figure out.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: no date is showing at all anymore when I did that...thank you for answering though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you to use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
beforeShowDay : function(date) {
    var date1 = new Date([2017, 02, 23]);
    var date2 = new Date([2017, 04, 14]);
    var date3 = new Date([2017, 06, 12]);
    var dateArray = [date1.getTime(), date2.getTime(), date3.getTime()];

    if (dateArray.indexOf(date.getTime()) == -1) {
        return {
            enabled: false
        };
    }
}
```

> From MDN: The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

In your code, this line:

```
dateArray.forEach(doBleh());
```

is wrong.

Instead to pass a callback function you are passing the result of a function execution.

Change it to:

```
dateArray.forEach(doBleh);
```

In any case a return inside the forEach is not the return of your beforeShowDay  function.

Comment: Nothing is getting disabled though, so this does not seem like it's working. It goes inside the if. I think it has to do with the return because it's returning to the foreach function, but not the main function

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you, can you explain your code please, i'll give it a thumbsup.

I don't understand the indexOf vs foreach and the == -1 confuses me

Comment: @Stephen: Answer improved. let me know.

Comment: perfect, maybe remove the foreach stuff you posted now that it's not relevant anymore...that is such a creative idea thank you, would have never thought of doing that! thanks!